# How to put image on button in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-button

I have a button with xml background. And I want to put image on  this button.
It is not possible to put two backgrounds in one button.
 So, is there other way of putting image on my button  while I have had a background yet?
Below the code of my button:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/readmore_back"
             />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you may use

```
<ImageButton
 ..
 ..
 ..
 android:src="@drawable/image1"
/>
```

instead of

```
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/readmore_back"
     />
```

Or

if you want to set the `image` to your existing `Button` then use

- `android:drawableTop`,
- `android:drawableBottom`,
- `android:drawableLeft`,
- `android:drawableRight`

Comment: What about the OP's custom background?  How would you configure an `ImageButton` to use this background?

Answer (score 0):

Use ImageButton instead of Button

```
<ImageButton
    android:src="@drawable/my_image"
    android:text="@string/IMAGE"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/battery"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/laughing"/>
```